# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS always creates new table (even if exsists)

Tags: php, database, mysqli, create-table

Pretty much self explanatory but for some reason it always works instead of working once (when table not exists)...

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','databasename');

$create_table =
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student  
(
    `1` longtext NOT NULL,
    `2` longtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;';

$create_tbl = $mysqli->query($create_table);

if ($create_table) {
    echo "Table has created";
}
else {
        echo "error!!";  
}
```

it always echo `Table has created` even if table is already exists!!!

Why?

Comment: Although the table exist the query is executed & return true values. As a result you got that message.

Comment: `$create_tbl` will be true even if no table was created, because the query has still executed successfully... the true response isn't whether a table has been created or not, it's a result from query succeeded/query failed

Comment: You're testing the SQL string, not the result!!!

Comment: @Mark Baker Oh... I got it... Thanks ! but... How can I manipulate it so I will get an error message if the table is existed...

Comment: Why do you want that? If you want an error if the table exists, why not just use `CREATE TABLE` without the `IF NOT EXISTS`? The whole point of the `IF NOT EXISTS` is to *avoid* an error message...

Comment: @Matt Gibson YEP! IT WORKS! I JUST REMOVED THE IF NOT EXISTS :)))) MANY THANKS !

Answer (score 2):

you have to check before if table exsit or not, because **$create_tbl** return 1 every time.
so run `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'student'` before

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','test');

$create_table =
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student  
(
    `1` longtext NOT NULL,
    `2` longtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;';


if(mysqli_num_rows($mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'student'")) !=1) {
    $create_tbl = $mysqli->query($create_table);
} else {
     echo "error!!";  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just removed the `IF NOT EXISTS` and it works like a charm! Thanks @Mark Baker for pointing this out! :)

Answer (score 1):

I never worked with the `MySQLi` API before(always using `PDO`), but doesn't it return true because the query actually was successful?

I think it only returns false if your connection failed, or an error like that.

Answer (score 1):

You're testing if the SQL statement exists, not the result. Nevertheless, you need to strictly test for the successful execution of the statement using `===` (not just `==` or testing the variable directly). Remove `IF NOT EXISTS` from the query and then test like this;

```
if ($create_tbl === true) {
    echo "Table was created";
}
else {
    echo "Error!!";
}
```

Comment: But "if not exists" means that the query will execute successfully, even if the table exists.